# React : Subrouting results in blank fullscreen, instead of appearing in <Box>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working with this react + redux + typescript website which uses Routing. I am not yet comfortable enough to understand everything here, but i'm trying my best :)

The thing is.. on one route.. i navigate to a component which has subroutes (using Tabs -> Tab navigation.. When i click one of these routes.. the page gets blank, like it's the wrong route..

**Working (parent) Route from Loan.tsx**

```
        <Route
          exact
          path="/loans/:loanID/cash-flow"
          render={() => (
            <Box pt={2} pb={2}>
              <CashFlowMain loanID={loanID} cashflow={cashflow} interestPayments={interestPayments} />
            </Box>
          )}
        />
```

**CashflowMain.tsx (which has the subroutes) :**

```
...
import {
  withRouter, Switch, Route, Link,
} from 'react-router-dom';
...

<Paper className={classes.card}>
  <Box m={2}>
    <Tabs className={classes.subTabs}>
      <Tab
        value="payments"
        label="Payments"
        disableRipple
        className={classes.tab}
        component={Link}
        to={{ pathname: `/loans/${loanID}/cash-flow/payments` }}
      />
 </Tabs>
</Box>
<Box m={2}>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/loans/:loanID/cash-flow/payments"
        render={() => (
           <Payments
              loanID={loanID}
              interestPayments={interestPayments}
            />
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
  </Box>
</Paper>
```

Comment: can you console log a hello world inside the cashflowmain component? if you see the log, then it's rendering the right component and then thats a different issue

Comment: I will try @CecilJohnTantay :)

Comment: Tried what you suggested... there is no log, no error.. nothing :)

Comment: kk then your assumption was correct. It has something to do with router. when you click on the new tab, does does your url on your params change? Can you post that url? It should have something like: `/loans/1/cash-flow/payments`

Comment: Url is correct yes :) 
http://localhost:3000/loans/the-long-guid-id/cash-flow/payments

Comment: My guess is that this is a minor bug that i have overlooked, due to my newbie competence in this area.. I first thought that it needed a different target than just a <Box>.. an id="sub-something", but referring to the docs, this should be sufficient..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the cashflowMain inside a  and make sure you have set up the correct route in the routing config file, you should add a path like "/loans/:loanID/cash-flow/:subTab", allso need to add that path/toute to loan.tsx

Comment: Ah!.. Ofcourse !.. That worked like magic :) Thanks a lot Maren :)